# Split qualifying colon-space separated strings in an array to form a new associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, text-parsing, delimited

I have an array named `$stat` that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => OK MPD 0.23.5
    [1] => repeat: 0
    [2] => random: 0
    [3] => single: 0
    [4] => consume: 1
    [5] => partition: default
    [6] => playlist: 11292
    [7] => playlistlength: 1
    [8] => mixrampdb: 0
    [9] => state: play
    [10] => song: 0
    [11] => songid: 3
    [12] => time: 14992:0
    [13] => elapsed: 14992.067
    [14] => bitrate: 48
    [15] => audio: 44100:16:2
    [16] => OK
)
```

I want to be able to use the array values (before the ":") as variables, instead of the numeric keys.

I need to do this, because the array keys returned change according to the player mode.

I have tried various methods, however I sense that my knowledge of PHP is simply not good enough to arrive at a solution.

The closest I have got is this:

```
foreach($stat as $list) {
        $list = trim($list);
//      echo "$list,";
        $list = "{$list}\n";
        $list = str_replace(": ", ",", $list);
        $xyz = explode(',', $list);
        $a=($xyz['0']);
        $b=($xyz['1']);
        echo "{$a}={$b}";
}
```

Which gives me this:

```
repeat=0
random=0
single=0
consume=1
partition=default
playlist=11642
playlistlength=1
mixrampdb=0
state=play
song=0
songid=3
time=15458:0
elapsed=15458.422
bitrate=50
audio=44100:16:2
```

If I try to create an array with the above output in the foreach loop, I end up with a multidimensional array which I can't seem to do anything with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure if I understand what you want, but something like this perhaps:

```
// Init new empty array
$newStat = [];

foreach ($stat as $value) {
        $value = trim($value);
        // It is not really necessary to replace this, but I kept it as is
        $value = str_replace(": ", ",", $value);
        $split = explode(',', $value);
        $key = $split[0];
        $newValue = $split[1];

        // Add to empty array
        $newStat[$key] = $newValue;
}

echo $newStat['time']; // 15458:0

// You can also do
foreach ($newStat as $key => $value) {
    // Whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseArray(array $array): array
{
  foreach($array as $value) {

    // IF the value is s string otherwise no cant do...
    if(is_string($value)) {

      // If we have a value after : otherwise set to null
      if(! str_contains($value, ':')) {
        $new[$value] = null;
        continue;
      }
    
      // Get data before ":" token as key and value after it.
      $key = substr($value, 0, strpos($value, ':'));
      $value = trim(str_replace($key.':', '', $value));
    
      $new[trim($key)] = $value;
    }
  
  }

  return $new ?? [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a focus on direct programming, looped `preg_match()` calls will concisely qualifying and extract data to be used as key-value pairs in the result array.

The pattern capture one or more non-colon characters, then matches the delimiting colon and space, then captures zero or more characters until the end of the string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/u9Zlm))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $v) {
    if (preg_match('/([^:]+): (.*)/', $v, $m)) {
        $result[$m[1]] = $m[2];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

As a funky, one-liner alternative, you can filter the array (to remove the values with no semicolons), replace the delimiting colon-space with an `=`, the implode with newlines, then parse the string-type payload as an ini string. This however demands that none of your string contain a newline or equals symbol. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lPJJh))

```
var_export(
    parse_ini_string(
        implode(
            "\n",
            preg_filter('/^[^:]+\K: /', '=', $array)
        )
    )
);
```